# Replication issue between two windows 2008 servers sites getting error

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

The following error occurred during the attempt to contact the domain controlled DC01: The RPC server is unavailable This condition may be caused by the DNS lookup problem

Comment: **What troubleshooting have you done? What is your site topology? What are your DCs' IP addresses? How are the DNS servers configured on each DC's network adapter? Can you actually resolve DC1 from the Server that is throwing this error?** You need to provide *way* more detail if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

The replication connection is attempting this process:

1. Look up other Domain Controller through DNS.
2. Connect to that IP address.
3. Establish a SMB connection.

Failures that happen after this point yield a different error.

By far the most common problem is that the DNS server used by the source DC can't resolve the destination DC for some reason. Once this is fixed, things start working.

Less common is the IP connection getting blocked in some way. Perhaps there is a firewall between the two points and it is blocking the wrong ports. The list of ports that need to be open between domain controllers is [quite extensive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179442#method3), so if this is being done, much care needs to be taken to it right.

Sometimes the firewall on the destination DC is blocking the connection. This is a very unusual thing, but does need looking at.

SMB connection failures mean the network path is completely clear, but something at the Windows level is broken. This is high-mojo, and there are no generic steps to fix it.